# How to perform GET requests on a JSON file in php?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a json file in the form of:

```
[{"label":"apple","desc":"fruit"},
{"label":"banana","desc":"fruit"},
{"label":"celery","desc":"vegetable"},
{"label":"plum","desc":"fruit"},
{"label":"","desc":"fruit"}]
```

How would I go about performing GET requests on this data?  For example

`http://www.mysite.com/data?desc=vegetable` would display `[{"label":"celery","desc":"vegetable"}]` to the browser and

`http://www.mysite.com/data?label=apple&desc=fruit` would display
`[{"label":"apple","desc":"fruit"}]` to the browser

Here is a working example that I would like to emulate:

http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON (returns nothing)
http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?featureClass=P&style=full&maxRows=12&name_startsWith=paris (returns matching cities.)

Jquery and php are the tools I'm using.  I'm trying to set this up so I can use jQuery UI autocomplete with a remote JSONP datasource.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have better results storing it in a database (e.g. MySQL).  Then, you can query based on `label` and `desc` columns.  Then, access the resulting row(s) with [`fetchObject`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) and convert the object directly to JSON with [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

You might need a few different versions of the query depending on what GET parameters they pass in.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for the advice. I'm really new to programming so forgive me.  But I have about 20k entries in my mysql database.  I've ran a query to sort by each parameter then limit the results to 10.  I set up the jQuery UI autocomplete and set the delay to 0.  The time it takes to suggest queries is about ~80ms per keystroke according to firebug.  Would this be faster if I exported all 20k entries to a json file and then perform get requests on the json file to retrieve the first 10 matches?

Comment: @LedZeppelin, no, I don't think parsing the JSON for each request will be faster.  You may be able to improve your query time by adding [indices](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Comment: oh okay sounds good.  I'll try it with json and get requests just to learn new stuff but I'm happy with the remote data source.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/getFood/',
         dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
             // do whatever you want with the data here (like show in a div)
        },
        // replace with whatever you wanna send in the querystring
        data: {'desc':'vegetable',},

    });
```

On the server side check the 'desc' parameter in your GET request and send appropriate response.

Comment: How would I get the browser to display the label and description in the json format after the get request is completed?  ex. `http://www.mysite.com/data?desc=vegetable` would display `[{"label":"celery","desc":"vegetable"}]` in the browser

Comment: I think if you instead of using a dataType of 'json' use 'html' and write your encoded json string as HTML from the server side, the browser should simply display it.

Comment: @Sid, "text" would be more appropriate.